# Shell Scripting - list head lines of files within directory

Tags: shell, sh

I am attempting to make a shell script that will display the head / tail lines of a file.

So the command will look something like:

```
scriptexample head 10 file.txt
```

Or have the option to select tail:

```
scriptexample tail 3 file.txt
```

Right now I'm trying to complete this but struggling to get it working.

```
filename=$1


if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
        echo "Command needs three arguments"
        exit
fi

head -n $filename
```

I put the -ne 3 as I assumed I will need around 3 arguments or so.

Also, later I am hoping to get it working with files within a directory once I get this part working.

Thank you.

Comment: the first line of your script should be `#!/bin/bash` (or the full path to the shell that you want to run your script). You should include that in the code you post. Also, when just learning, it's better to leave on the training wheels to be sure things are working as expected. I would add an explicit `else "echo found 3 args and will process this request" ;` to your `if ... fi` block. Then read up about `case $var pat1* ) echo action 1 ;; pat2* ) echo action 2 ;; * ) echo default action ;; esac` and the `shift` command to remove args from the command line after you have assigned them. ...

Comment: Note that you have 3 arguments, so you should be using `$1, $2, $3` OR using `shift` 2 times in your script to assign cmd-line arg values to variables in your script (as you have done with `filename=`.  Good luck!

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is the motivation for such a wrapper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look carefully which arguments you have.

```
usage() {
   echo "scriptexample [head|tail] nr_of_lines filename"
   exit 1
}

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
   usage
fi

command="$1"
nr_of_lines="$2"
filename="$3"

if [ ! -f "${filename}" ]; then
   echo "${filename} is not a regular file"
   usage
fi
# todo: check argument 2 for positive number

case "${command}" in
   head)
      head -${nr_of_lines} "${filename}"
      ;;
   tail)
      tail -${nr_of_lines} "${filename}"
      ;;
   *)
      usage;;
esac
```

Comment: Great that cleared up a lot for me and I can actually understand the script you wrote.